# How to select one element instead of all elements using 'clicked' in a Django for loop

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

In my Django project I am trying to create a feature so that when someone clicks the cog element on my folder, it adds a class to only the one folder element I have clicked.

My issue is that when I click the cog, it apply's the class to all of the other folders, and not just the one I want. I understand why it is doing this, but not sure how to fix it.

When I click the cog

[image]

It applys the css to all elements and not just the one I clicked with the cog.

[image]

HTML

```
        {% for video in videos %}
            {% if video.active %}
                <div class="folder">
                    <div class="folder-settings-tool" onclick="folderSettings(this)">
                        <!-- CHANGE COLOUR OF THE SETTINGS COG TO WHITE -->
                        <img src="{% static 'public/image/icons/settings-work-tool.svg' %}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="folder-settings">
                        <div class="title-change">
                            <p class="title-rename">RENAME</p><input type="text" name="title">
                        </div>
                        <div class="archive">
                            <p class="archive-text">
                                ARCHIVE
                            </p>
                            <label class="switch">
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                <span class="slider round"></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="make-final">
                            <p class="archive-text">
                                MAKE FINAL
                            </p>
                            <label class="switch">
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                <span class="slider round"></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="downloadable">
                            <p class="archive-text">
                                DOWNLOADABLE
                            </p>
                            <label class="switch">
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                <span class="slider round"></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a href="{% url 'public:file_detail' model='video' pk=video.pk %}">
                        <div class="folder-text">
                            <p>VIDEO</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="{% static 'public/image/icons/folders.svg' %}">
                        </div>
                        <div class="folder-info">
                            <div class="folder-title">   
                                {{ video.title }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="folder-date">
                                <p><span class="folder-created">Created</span> {{ video.created }}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
```

jQuery:

```
    function folderSettings(element) {
        if($(element).data('clicked')) {
            $(".folder").removeClass("folder-hidden");
            $(element).data('clicked', false);
        } else {
            $(".folder").addClass("folder-hidden");
            $(element).data('clicked', true);
        }
    };
```

Comment: "{% for video in videos %}" does your video has some unique attribute .. name or id or something? That would be my starting point to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get particular div with class `folder` ,so you can use `parent()` method of jquery ,and get parent element of clicked element , i.e :

```js
function folderSettings(element) {
  if ($(element).data('clicked')) {
    //getting parent div and remove class
    $(element).parent().removeClass("folder-hidden");
    $(element).data('clicked', false);
  } else {
    //getting parent div and add class
    $(element).parent().addClass("folder-hidden");
    $(element).data('clicked', true);
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="folder">
  <div class="folder-settings-tool" onclick="folderSettings(this)">
    <!-- CHANGE COLOUR OF THE SETTINGS COG TO WHITE -->
    <img src="{% static 'public/image/icons/settings-work-tool.svg' %}">
  </div>
  <div class="folder-settings">
    <div class="title-change">
      <p class="title-rename">RENAME</p><input type="text" name="title">
    </div>
    <div class="archive">
      <p class="archive-text">
        ARCHIVE
      </p>
      <label class="switch">
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                <span class="slider round"></span>
                            </label>
    </div>
    <div class="make-final">
      <p class="archive-text">
        MAKE FINAL
      </p>
      <label class="switch">
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                <span class="slider round"></span>
                            </label>
    </div>
    <div class="downloadable">
      <p class="archive-text">
        DOWNLOADABLE
      </p>
      <label class="switch">
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                <span class="slider round"></span>
                            </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="{% url 'public:file_detail' model='video' pk=video.pk %}">
    <div class="folder-text">
      <p>VIDEO</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="{% static 'public/image/icons/folders.svg' %}">
    </div>
    <div class="folder-info">
      <div class="folder-title">
        {{ video.title }}
      </div>
      <div class="folder-date">
        <p><span class="folder-created">Created</span> {{ video.created }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="folder">
  <div class="folder-settings-tool" onclick="folderSettings(this)">
    <!-- CHANGE COLOUR OF THE SETTINGS COG TO WHITE -->
    <img src="{% static 'public/image/icons/settings-work-tool.svg' %}">
  </div>
  <div class="folder-settings">
    <div class="title-change">
      <p class="title-rename">RENAME</p><input type="text" name="title">
    </div>
    <div class="archive">
      <p class="archive-text">
        ARCHIVE
      </p>
      <label class="switch">
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                <span class="slider round"></span>
                            </label>
    </div>
    <div class="make-final">
      <p class="archive-text">
        MAKE FINAL
      </p>
      <label class="switch">
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                <span class="slider round"></span>
                            </label>
    </div>
    <div class="downloadable">
      <p class="archive-text">
        DOWNLOADABLE
      </p>
      <label class="switch">
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                <span class="slider round"></span>
                            </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="{% url 'public:file_detail' model='video' pk=video.pk %}">
    <div class="folder-text">
      <p>VIDEO</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="{% static 'public/image/icons/folders.svg' %}">
    </div>
    <div class="folder-info">
      <div class="folder-title">
        {{ video.title }}
      </div>
      <div class="folder-date">
        <p><span class="folder-created">Created</span> {{ video.created }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="folder">
  <div class="folder-settings-tool" onclick="folderSettings(this)">
    <!-- CHANGE COLOUR OF THE SETTINGS COG TO WHITE -->
    <img src="{% static 'public/image/icons/settings-work-tool.svg' %}">
  </div>
  <div class="folder-settings">
    <div class="title-change">
      <p class="title-rename">RENAME</p><input type="text" name="title">
    </div>
    <div class="archive">
      <p class="archive-text">
        ARCHIVE
      </p>
      <label class="switch">
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                <span class="slider round"></span>
                            </label>
    </div>
    <div class="make-final">
      <p class="archive-text">
        MAKE FINAL
      </p>
      <label class="switch">
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                <span class="slider round"></span>
                            </label>
    </div>
    <div class="downloadable">
      <p class="archive-text">
        DOWNLOADABLE
      </p>
      <label class="switch">
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                <span class="slider round"></span>
                            </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="{% url 'public:file_detail' model='video' pk=video.pk %}">
    <div class="folder-text">
      <p>VIDEO</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="{% static 'public/image/icons/folders.svg' %}">
    </div>
    <div class="folder-info">
      <div class="folder-title">
        {{ video.title }}
      </div>
      <div class="folder-date">
        <p><span class="folder-created">Created</span> {{ video.created }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```